# Not even able to Log in

Tags: menus

I am so stressed and frustrated by this I think I am going to crack in half. Please Help! I can't even log in to work on my WordPress site. I used Google Domains to get to Word Press website building in the first place but when I try to log in through WordPress.org it doesn't have any of my email addresses as registered and I can't get through and you can't seem to contact anyone at Word Press directly... SOOOOOOOOOO FRUSTRATING AND STRESSFUL! If anyone has any idea what the hell is going on I would GREATLY appreciate the assistance!!!

Comment: It keeps saying "there is no registered email address" etc. even though it sends password reset notifications to that email address... I have no idea what username and password it has saved but I am stuck in an eternal feedback loop...

Answer (score 1):

WordPress.org has its own accounts for the support forums and it has nothing to do with the logins for your website, or for WordPress.com, the hosted version of WordPress. When you self-host a website with the WordPress responsibility the management of your logins is your responsibility and no one at WordPress.org or WordPress.com can help.

You only mentioned Google Domains though. That has nothing to do with WordPress or hosting a website. If you signed up for a website at WordPress.com, then you need to contact *them* for any help with your account. Their support page is [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com). But if all you've done so far is sign up for Google Domains, then you don't have a website with either of these services, and need to find a host to set up a WordPress site for you.

Comment: Through Google Domains I selected Word Press and registered for hosting on a free 30 day trial with charges to start thereafter. I am beyond just the domain registration - I have been building the site. I was using the more robust .org tools, I am sure of it. But I can't get back to that point - it wasn't through their download, but some online version of the platform. I can log in to the .com, but when I attempt to do certain things, like customize the theme, it takes me to a login page I can't get past (the .org admin entry, I think) and which doesn't recognize my email addresses/passwords.

Comment: In digging in a bit more it appears that Google Domains signs you up for WordPress on Bluehost. You should try contacting them. They would he hosting a .org install of WordPress for you, but you would never actually sign in to wordpress.org (or .com) to do anything with it. You would only be signing into your website which has its own account that would've been created by or for you. Bluehost would be the best people to ask next.

Comment: That was totally it. I had to get there through Blue Host. Thank you so much man, you just took away some serious stress! I wish I was calmer sometimes...